# Quadratic Matrix programming

Tags: matrix-equations, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

I would like to find a numerical solution to the following quadratic matrix programming problem. Square matrix A has thousands of rows, so I need a algorithm which works fast. I looked into Python but couldnt find much there. Is there something in Matlab, Mathematica, or elsewhere.

$A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix of coefficients represented by $a_{ij}$. I know the zero entries (see constraint 4). The optimization problem is to compute the coefficients of matrix A.

\begin{aligned}
\underset{\{a_{ij}\}}{\text{minimize}}
& & \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (a_{ij})^2
\\\\
& \text{constraint 1}
& & Ax = x
\\\\
& \text{constraint 2}
& & a_{ij} \geq 0 \text{  }  \forall i,j
\\\\
& \text{constraint 3}
& & \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} = 1  \text{  }  \forall i
\\\\
& \text{constraint 4}
& & a_{ij} = 0 \text{  } \forall a_{ij} \in B 
\end{aligned}

Where B is a collection of tuples indicating which elements of A is zero. For example, $B=[a_{01}, a_{02}, a_{31} ]$, means $a_{01}, a_{02}, a_{31}$ are zeros in $A$.

And x is fixed vector.

[the problem in latex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4bAu.jpg)

Comment: Is $x$ some fixed vector? Then you can look at quadratic programming (QP) or second-order cone programming (SOCP). Both Matlab and Pyton/Scipy have solvers for QPs but there is also tons of other software for those problems.

Comment: yes x is a fixed vector

Comment: Then your formulation is a straightforward QP or SOCP with the $a_{ij}$ as variables.

Comment: In the case SOCP is expensive for you ($A$ seems to be big), you can formulate your problem as a convex-concave saddle point and apply simpler and cheaper first-order methods.